# how to change fonrs for Indian reqgional language?

Tags: multi-language, language

Google and wordprees provides 100s of cool fonts for English. How do I add a new font in a language that is not English. (In my case Kannada). Are there any plugins to add fonts?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy, and you can follow along with this tutorial [How to Add Custom Fonts in WordPress](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-fonts-in-wordpress/) specially the way under the heading  **Adding Custom Fonts in WordPress Using CSS3 @font-face** :

The most direct way of adding custom fonts in WordPress is by adding the fonts using CSS3 @font-face method. This method allows you to use any font that you like on your website.

First thing you need to do is download the font that you like in a web format. If you do not have the web format for your font, then you can convert it using the [FontSquirrel Webfont generator.](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

Once you have the webfont files, you would need to upload it on your web hosting server.

The best place to upload the fonts is inside a new “fonts” folder in your theme or child theme‘s directory.

You can use FTP or File Manager of your cPanel to upload the font.

Once you have uploaded the font, you need to load the font in your theme’s stylesheet using CSS3 @font-face rule like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Arvo;  
src: url(http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/fonts/Arvo-Regular.ttf);  
font-weight: normal;  
}
```

Don’t forget to replace the font-family and URL with your own.

After that you can use that font anywhere in your theme’s stylesheet like this:

```
.h1 site-title { 
    font-family: "Arvo", Arial, sans-serif; 
 }
```